# flutter image_picker package compile error [ it works under 0.6.0 but not over ]

Tags: image, flutter, compilation, version, picker

when I run flutter i got these messages.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G930S in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :location_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :firebase_auth_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@116a0403' was deleted, but previous version not found in cache

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

my pubspect.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  animated_floatactionbuttons: ^0.1.0
  awesome_dialog: ^1.1.3
  awsome_video_player: ^1.0.8+1
  badges: ^1.1.1
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  carousel_slider: ^2.2.1
  cached_network_image: ^2.2.0+1
  cached_video_player: ^1.0.3
  email_validator: ^1.0.5
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
  flutter_bloc: ^6.0.1
  flutter_money_formatter: ^0.8.2
  flutter_gifimage: ^1.0.0
  flutter_speed_dial: ^1.2.5
  flutter_styled_toast: ^1.3.0
  flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
  flutter_svg: ^0.17.0
  fluttertoast: ^7.0.2
  flick_video_player: ^0.1.1
  get: ^3.4.6
  getwidget: ^1.1.3
  geolocator: ^5.3.2+2
  google_nav_bar: ^2.2.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.30
  http: ^0.12.2
  image_stack: ^1.1.0
  image_picker: ^0.5.4+3
  path_provider: ^1.6.11
  path: ^1.6.4
  line_icons: ^0.2.0
  location: ^3.0.0
  logger: ^0.9.2
  provider: ^4.3.2+1
  url_launcher: ^5.5.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.8
  smooth_star_rating: ^1.1.1
  regexpattern: ^0.2.3
  video_player: ^0.10.12
  video_player_controls: ^2.1.6


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Flutter Doctor report

```
[√] Flutter (Channel unknown, v1.17.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1016], locale ko-KR)
• Flutter version 1.17.5 at C:\src\flutter
• Framework revision 8af6b2f038 (8 weeks ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
• Engine revision ee76268252
• Dart version 2.8.4

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\Silenmus\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin version 48.0.2
• Dart plugin version 193.7361
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.47.3)
• VS Code at C:\Users\Silenmus\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.13.2

[√] Connected device (2 available)
• SM G930S • ce0416040ac8423d04 • android-arm64 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26)
• sdk gphone x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
```

I tried these to solve this problem

1. made new project and all copy of my project packages and run it
   => it works == I think it's not packages dependency problem
2. run AVD same error occurs
3. Changed image_picker version
   => ^0.5.4+3 works
   => over ^0.6.0 doesn't

I have no idea what's wrong with me or code or package or flutter

Comment: i also have your problem,  Probably, the flutter plugin has the same xml, so it seems that there is a conflict. At that time, I tested by removing plugins one by one.

Comment: i removed unused packages
`
#  animated_floatactionbuttons: ^0.1.0
#  awsome_video_player: ^1.0.8+1
#  cached_video_player: ^1.0.3
#  flutter_bloc: ^6.0.1
#  regexpattern: ^0.2.3
#  flick_video_player: ^0.1.1
`
and i works , thanks man 

Answer (score 0):

```
#  animated_floatactionbuttons: ^0.1.0
#  awsome_video_player: ^1.0.8+1
#  cached_video_player: ^1.0.3
#  flutter_bloc: ^6.0.1
#  regexpattern: ^0.2.3
#  flick_video_player: ^0.1.1
```

i remove unused packages and it works
if someone who like me ,
remove package one by one it could save your debugging time.